# Mixing Native SQL with Default Hibernate Behavior in an Entity Object?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, nativequery

I'm trying to work a native sql query into an existing entity object while retaining the default Hibernate behavior for the object as a whole.

The majority of the fields on the object are mapped as so:

```
@Column(name = "FIRST_NAME", nullable = false)
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

@Column(name = "MIDDLE_NAME", nullable = true)
public String getMiddleName() {
    return middleName;
}

@Column(name = "LAST_NAME", nullable = false)
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

@Column(name = "PRIMARY_EMAIL_ADDR", nullable = false)
public String getPrimaryEmailAddress() {
    return primaryEmailAddress;
}
```

I want to retain this functionality, but add a single field for which I need mapping to a custom (preferably native) SQL Query.  I envisioned something like...

```
Private String foo;
@NativeSQLQuery("SELECT info FROM foo")
public String getFooInfo{return foo}
```

..but if there is a way to do this as simply as that, I'm missing it.

I've investigated `SqlResultSetMapping` and several similar Native and Named Query annotations, but all that I can find seems to presume that one is operating at the class level - that the entire entity is mapped in a custom, native fashion, not just one field.  How can I go about *keeping* the normal functionality, but adding the custom mapping for one field?  I've done this before using hbm files, I think, quite some time ago, but this current project is annotation-based.  At the moment, the best I can come up with is to mark the getter `@Transient` and to not map it at all, but just use it to execute a query, but I'd really rather not do that, just because it seems like a total hack.

Comment: Is it really that bad to create a new entity for the data you're looking to join with?  Or if you're not joining, to just simply fetch it directly from a separate entity?

Comment: That would make sense, but unfortunately in this case that's not an option.  It needs to be integrated with the existing entity, but draw its value from a custom query rather than from a column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a `@Formula("SELECT info FROM foo")`, should works